# Rails update to 6.0.1: errors when the config.load_defaults is changed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

I'm currently updating a Rails application from 5.2.4 to 6.0.1.
I used the `rails app:update` task, fixed some depreciations, then uncommented the changes in `new_framework_defaults_6_0.rb`, one by one. Everything works, all tests are validated, so I remove the `new_framework_defaults_6_0.rb` file and change the config to load the new defaults, with `config.load_defaults 6.0` and... badaboum.

I'm able to start the rails server, but I have an error with Puma:

```
Puma caught this error: uninitialized constant Admin (call 'Admin.connection' to establish a connection)::Concerns
Did you mean?  Concurrent (NameError)
/Users/xx/xx/app/models/admin.rb:4:in `<class:Admin>'
/Users/xx/xx/app/models/admin.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/xx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5@xx/gems/zeitwerk-2.2.2/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:16:in `require'
/Users/xx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5@xx/gems/zeitwerk-2.2.2/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:16:in `require'
...
```

If I refresh, I have another error:

```
Before process_action callback :authenticate_user has not been defined
```

*(the method exists)*

And, finally, if I refresh once again:

```
undefined method `signed_in?' for #<#<Class:0x00007fc47a7706f0>:0x00007fc47a783a70>
```

These methods exists in my code, not in a Gem.
It's like if some files are not loaded. 
I don't know what is the problem, the `config.load_defaults 6.0` does the same thing that when there's the `new_framework_defaults_6_0.rb` so why it works with the file but not with `config.load_defaults 6.0` ?

Any help would be really appreciated

Ruby 2.6.5
Rails 6.0.1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, the solution was pretty simple, I didn't noticed that the autoloader was a new... Rails uses the `zeitwerk` autoloader by default with rails 6.0:

```
def load_defaults(target_version)
  case target_version.to_s
  when "5.0"
    […]
  when "5.2"
    load_defaults "5.1"
    […]
  when "6.0"
    load_defaults "5.2"

    self.autoloader = :zeitwerk if RUBY_ENGINE == "ruby"

    […]
  else
    raise "Unknown version #{target_version.to_s.inspect}"
  end

  @loaded_config_version = target_version
end
```

And there's this method to choose the autoloader:

```
def autoloader=(autoloader)
  case autoloader
  when :classic
    @autoloader = autoloader
  when :zeitwerk
    require "zeitwerk"
    @autoloader = autoloader
  else
    raise ArgumentError, "config.autoloader may be :classic or :zeitwerk, got #{autoloader.inspect} instead"
  end
end
```

So I just changed my `application.rb` to use the classic autoloader:

```
config.load_defaults 6.0
config.autoloader = :classic
```

Everything works now

Comment: Yah that approach is written in Rails guide as well 
https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v6.0/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html#opting-out